# Merging two table entries with unique columns (MySQL)

Tags: mysql

I know full well this should never happen. Ever. However, I started working at a company recently that hasn't had the greatest database design or input validation and this situation has come up.

There is a table which we'll call 'jobs'*. Jobs has a primary key, 'ID'. The job with the ID of 1 has loads of data associated with it; However, stupidly someone has duplicated that job as id 2 (this has happened around ~500 times so far). All of the information for both needs to be merged as id 1 (or 2, it doesn't matter).

The columns ARE linked by Foreign Key with UPDATE: CASCADE and DELETE: RESTRICT. They are not all called jobs_id.

Is my only (seemingly sensible) option here to:

1. Change id 1 to something I can guarantee is not used (2,147,483,647)
2. Temporarily remove the Foreign Key DELETE: RESTRICT
3. Delete the entry with id 1
4. Update id 2 to 2,147,483,647 (to link it with all the other entries)
5. Change id 2,147,483,647 to id 2
6. Reinstate DELETE: RESTRICT

As none of the code actually performs a delete (the restriction is there just as a fail-safe (someone editing direct in DB)), and the update: cascade is left in, data shouldn't get out of sync. This does seem messy though.

This will be wrapped in a transaction.

I could write something to iterate through each table (~180) and each column to find certain names / conditions, then update from 1 to 2, but that would need maintenance when a new table / column came along.

As this has happened a lot, and I don't see a re-write to prevent it happening any time soon, the 'solution' (sticking plaster) needs to be semi-automatic.

- not the table's real name. His (or her) identity has been disguised so he (or she) doesn't get bullied.

Appreciate any input.

Comment: Before I try and answer this add the following items to the steps. 1. Do a full backup. 2. Test backup on another machine i.e. restore to a dev environment for example.

Comment: This was always going to be tested in a dev environment before executing on the production server.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you know how to identify the duplicated records why not create a new table with the same structure (maybe without the FKs), then loop through the original while copying values to the new table. When you hit a duplication, fix the value when writing to the new table. Then drop the original and rename the temp to the original.

This will clean up the table but if processes are still making the duplicated entries you could use a unique key to limit the damage going forward.